# Irish Green Card waiting time?

Tags: working-visas, greencard, ireland

I'm living in a European, non-EU/EEA country, and have been working for a startup from the Republic of Ireland, through a contractor, for the last 6 months. They've just asked me to move to Ireland to work for them directly. I'm an ICT professional, so would qualify for their Green Card programme.

Does anyone have experience as to what the waiting time is for approval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This link: http://www.djei.ie/labour/workpermits/processingdates.htm can give you a clue.
Normally, it will take something between 3 or 4 weeks.